# "No such file or directory - /public/settings.xml" in Rails when the file is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana3, webrick

As you can see, the file is there.  I made sure to switch rights to that file to everyone - anythiig I am missing that is obvious?

[image]

[image]

Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.0.3

Comment: What's throwing that error, can you show us some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `/` before `public`, as it is searching for `public` directory in root , so for example, if you wanted to remove the file from a terminal you would say:

`rm public/settings.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Rails serves up files in the `public` directory from the root of the application. So instead of using `/public/settings.xml` as the path in the browser, you should just use `/settings.xml`